# ZEND PDF Order Creation on new page

Tags: magento2, zend-framework, purchase-order

I have used this code to make a Custom PDF to make purchase orders also with some custom attributes but the base code is the same: https://webkul.com/blog/generate-pdf-programmatically-magento2/
This works great, however when the amount of products is for example >10 and it doesn't fit on the page anymore, instead of making a new page and continuing it prints it all on 1 page and it goes off screen, the data is there when u select all text on PDF just not visible.
How can i use this code to create a page break when the amount of products doesn't fit on page anymore?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use or copy the core method *\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice::newPage*
that add a new blank page to your pdf.

I also just wrote a custom class to render invoice as PDF on magento 2, and as I loop through all invoice items, I check if the Y position is high enough (page bottom is 0), else I add a new page and set the Y position to the top of that page.